# Correspondence of the entry in "select" to the entry in the field

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to edit a record in which there is a field from another table, so I use «Select» in which I pull the relevant data from another table. But when I open the form for editing, the item in the «Select» is always the first, and it needs to correspond to the one in the record that is subject to editing.

Now I need to always select the appropriate item in the "select" so that it is not accidentally replaced by the first one.

update.php

```
$User = mysqli_query($connect, query: "SELECT * FROM `User`");
$animal = mysqli_query($connect, query: "SELECT * FROM `Animals` WHERE `Animal_id` = '$id'");


    <p>Alias:</p>
    <input type="text" name="breed" value="<?=$animal['Animal_Breed']?>">

    <p>Owner:</p>
    <select name="users">
        <?php foreach($User as $rows):?>
            <option value="<?php echo $rows['id'];?>"><?php echo $rows['Name'];?></option>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </select>
```

Comment: You mean you want to add a `selected` attribute to the select field?  There will be dozens of Stack Overflow pages that demonstrate that. Are you asking about how to fetch `$animal` data? I don't see a clear [mcve].

Comment: @zorax8137 You need to get `id` of the owner in case if page is visited by the user who owning his animal and have rights to edit. You can pass this id as a parameter in the url query string or get it from controller or whatsoever. Then add a condition in the `foreach` loop which will check for example `<option value="..." <?php if ($_GET['user_id'] === $rows['id']): ?>selected<?php endif;?>>`

Comment: I want the same attribute to be selected according to the "<?=$animal['Owner_id']?>" in selected. When I edit a record, I write "users" to the "Animals" table. But "users" cannot always be edited by the user. Since it always starts with the first attribute, this first attribute replaces the attribute in the record.

Comment: `<option value="..." <?php if ($animal['Owner_id'] === $rows['id']): ?>selected<?php endif;?>>` like this ?

Comment: `<select name="users">
        <?php foreach($User as $rows):?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rows['id'];?>"<?php if ($animal['Owner_id'] === $rows['id']):?>selected<?php endif;?></option>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </select>` Unfortunately, it does not work, does not list any records.

Comment: `<option value="<?php echo $rows['id'];?>" <?php if ($animal['Owner_id'] === $rows['id']): ?>selected<?php endif;?>><?php echo $rows['Name'];?></option>`

Comment: @SergeyLigus I am very grateful to you, it works, I wish you success and good health.